# How view knows about its viewmodel in WPF MVVM

Tags: .net, wpf, mvvm

It may sound silly, but please let me know how exactly a view know about which viewmodel it must bind to because I dont see any reference of viewmodel inside a sample view's code-behind class.

Comment: Sometimes the DataContext is set in the XAML

Comment: It would be better if you could provide a code sample.

Comment: Sometimes it is done through a ViewModelLocator style pattern. Sometimes it is achieved using `[Import]` and `[Export]` tags to set the `DataContext` of the view to the viewmodel interface. Sometimes the `DataContext` is just directly set in the view constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You'll find a property called `DataContext` in your pages and controls. That's what the bindings point to.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a sample View. The View knows about its ViewModel because of the DataType attribute on the DataTemplate tag. In this example there is a .NET assembly called MyCompany.MyViewModels.dll. There is a ViewModel called MyViewModel.cs. There is a property on MyViewModel.cs called MyViewModelPropertyName.

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MyCompany.MyViewModels">

   <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:MyViewModel}">
       <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyViewModelPropertyName}" />
   </DataTemplate>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: Please let me know the reason for the down vote so I can correct my error.

Comment: Not my down vote but your answer relates to templates not views

Comment: Okay, I assumed that "View" was generic for "Xaml" ... Isn't a DataTemplate a type of View?

Comment: Not really, more like a style. View would be more likely a user control or window.